# How to draw a BufferedImage to a tooltip

Tags: java, swing, base64, tooltip, bufferedimage

I wonder if it is possible to draw a `BufferedImage` to a regular tooltip.

As described [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Useimagesintooltips.htm), an image may be placed into a tooltip by using HTML and an image element pointing to the URL of the image. So I tried to encode the `BufferedImage` in base64 like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377711/1796523) and used the following HTML as tooltip text:

```
"<html><img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encode(out.toByteArray()) + "\"></html>"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Am I missing something or are the HTML capabilities of a tooltip too limited to support base64 encoded images? Is there any other way to display a dynamically generated image like a tooltip?

Comment: Java's interpretation of HTML is simplistic.  It does not support `data` based URLs.  If you can write the image somewhere (e.g. the temp directory) see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26795598/418556) for how to load it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Writing the image to disk is no option since it may change quickly. It doesn't *have* to use an actual tooltip, too; this was just the only idea I've been able to come up with so far. All I want is to display the image like it were a tooltip of some component.